# Pandas Dataframe Multicolor Line plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a DateTime index and two column representing Wind Speed and ambient Temperature. Here is the data for half a day

```
                        temp        winds

2014-06-01 00:00:00     8.754545    0.263636
2014-06-01 01:00:00     8.025000    0.291667
2014-06-01 02:00:00     7.375000    0.391667
2014-06-01 03:00:00     6.850000    0.308333
2014-06-01 04:00:00     7.150000    0.258333
2014-06-01 05:00:00     7.708333    0.375000
2014-06-01 06:00:00     9.008333    0.391667
2014-06-01 07:00:00     10.858333   0.300000
2014-06-01 08:00:00     12.616667   0.341667
2014-06-01 09:00:00     15.008333   0.308333
2014-06-01 10:00:00     17.991667   0.491667
2014-06-01 11:00:00     21.108333   0.491667
2014-06-01 12:00:00     21.866667   0.395238
```

I would like to plot this data as one line where the color changes according to temperature. So from light red to dark red the higher the temperature for example.

I found this [example of multicolored](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb) lines with matplotlib but I have no idea how to use this with a pandas DataFrame. Has anyone an idea what I could do? 
If it is possible to do this, would it also be possible as additional feature to change the width of the line according to wind speed? So the faster the wind the wider the line.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build-in `plot` method in `pandas` probably won't be able to do it. You need to extract the data and plot them using `matplotlib`.

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.dates as mpd

x=mpd.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())
y=df.winds.values
c=df['temp'].values
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=plt.get_cmap('copper'), norm=plt.Normalize(0, 10))
lc.set_array(c)
lc.set_linewidth(3)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.xlim(min(x), max(x))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpd.HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpd.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S'))
_=plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70 )
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]

There are two issues worth mentioning,

the range of the color gradient is controlled by `norm=plt.Normalize(0, 10)`

`pandas` and `matplotlib` plot time series differently, which requires the `df.index` to be converted to `float` before plotting. And by modifying the `major_locators`, we will get the `xaxis majorticklabels` back into date-time format.

The second issue may cause problem when we want to plot more than just one lines (the data will be plotted in two separate x ranges):

```
#follow what is already plotted:
df['another']=np.random.random(13)
print ax.get_xticks()
df.another.plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
print ax.get_xticks(minor=True)

[ 735385.          735385.04166667  735385.08333333  735385.125
  735385.16666667  735385.20833333  735385.25        735385.29166667
  735385.33333333  735385.375       735385.41666667  735385.45833333
  735385.5       ]
[389328 389330 389332 389334 389336 389338 389340]
```

Therefore we need to do it without `.plot()` method of `pandas`:

```
ax.twinx().plot(x, df.another)
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great and works perfectly. Can you tell me by chance how to add a colorbar for the colored line?

Comment: I solved the problem with my colorbar :) Any Idea how to add a second line to such a plot with a separate y axis? I just tried df['anotherline'].plot(ax=axes, secondary_y=True) but that screws the whole plot. Even without secondary_y the plot is no longer showing anything

Comment: See edit, just need `ax.twinx().plot(x, df.another)`. Cheers!