# converting timestamps into plot-able array of values

Tags: python, time, strptime

I have an array of time values = [hh:mm:ss] with seconds as decimals like 13.80 seconds, 15.90 seconds and so on. What I am trying to do:

```
import time

for i in timestamp_array:
   new_time = time.strptime(i,"%H:%M:%S")
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .80
```

How do I deal with this?
Thank you!

Comment: if I try to parse it with try and except ValueError within the for loop, I get an error saying that the time data doesn't match the specified format. Please help!!!

Comment: I understand the problem here is that the seconds decimal goes from 0-61 and I have values going above 61. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: By plot do you mean `matplotlib`? In that case, you can use `matplotlib.dates`, especially the `datestr2num()` method.

Comment: but it's not date values, would it still work? it's time values

Comment: Yep, it will work with time vales, see the example below. And you can set the ticklables in almost any datetime format, see example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590142/pandas-dataframe-multicolor-line-plot/24593105#24593105

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to plot the values, I will suggest using `matplotlib.dates`, you can convert time to numbers and backwards as well.

```
In [12]:
import matplotlib.dates as mpd
mpd.datestr2num('12:23:12')

Out[12]:
735420.5161111112

In [13]:
mpd.num2date(735420.5161111112)

Out[13]:
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 6, 12, 23, 12, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x051FD9F0>)
```

An minimal example:

```
plt.plot([mpd.datestr2num('12:23:12.89'), mpd.datestr2num('12:23:13.89')],
         [1,2], 'o')
ax=plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpd.HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpd.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

[image]

Comment: I have the seconds in decimals going above 61

Comment: Such as `'12:23:61'`? I think that will raise an exception. But `12:23:12.81` will work alright.

Comment: awesome! works, but how do I plot with displaying the actual string of time values, because the 735420.51611112 isn't that great for display

Comment: I want the x axis to show the actual time stamp values, any suggestions for that?

Comment: nevermind, figured it out using matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(array of 735420.5161111112, values)

Comment: A minimal example was added. Basically you just need to choose a suitable locator and then a suitable formatter for the x axis tick labels.

Comment: `plot_date` will do too. :)

Comment: what formatter can I use for timestamp that has no date and looks like this 12:23:12.81 with hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: Could be just `mpd.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f')`

Comment: According to your example, the last line ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpd.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f')) gives error: ERROR: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<stdin>, line 1) [unknown]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpd.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f))
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You are missing a `'` after `%f`

Comment: I did put the apostrophe after %f, maybe you can zoom in and see. Not sure why it's still not working. Any other suggestions would be really helpful, thank you!!!