# Matplotlib: How to use two colors in a single line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am getting a list of `close` data which is both negative and positive. When I plot a line I want to show positive value as a green segment and negative value as a red segment. I have data in the following df format:

```
                                A       price     B         side  size  signal  \
time                                                                            
2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990  4603.35936  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    20    True   
2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990  4603.24884  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    38    True   
2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990  4603.26808  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    69    True   
2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990  4603.32670  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    25    True   
2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990  4603.32670  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy   450    True   
...                                ...     ...         ...  ...   ...     ...   
2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863  3997.85136  8043.5  4375.44562  Buy    22   False   
2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863  3997.87648  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy  1300   False   
2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863  3997.87616  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy     6   False   
2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863  3997.89530  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy  1000   False   
2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863  3997.90046  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy   280   False
```

If the signal is True show green else red. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24593105/275002) example but I am struggling to understand it.

The code I have tried so far is below

```
first=combine[:200000] #DF
x = first.index
y = first.price.values
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
from  matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rg',["r", "g"], N=256) 
print(cmap)
```

I am unable to figure out how to use `Signal` value to color segments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the line color in units of data sections in a line chart, you need to convert the data used for the line chart to (x1,y1),(x2,y2). Then create a list to set the color for that section. For each data, specify the plotting function; the time series on the x-axis will be updated last. It may be possible to deal with the time series as it is, but I think it is easier to deal with it as a vector and then deal with it as a time series later. This is a hint for this answer. What I am modifying from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121773/python-is-it-possible-to-change-line-color-in-a-plot-if-exceeds-a-specific-rang) is the way the last value is specified since the data used is a pandas series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
time A       price     B         side  size  signal 
"2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990"  4603.35936  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    20    True   
"2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990"  4603.24884  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    38    True   
"2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990"  4603.26808  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    69    True   
"2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990"  4603.32670  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy    25    True   
"2019-06-12 03:54:26.668990"  4603.32670  7990.0  4583.96620  Buy   450    True   
"2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863"  3997.85136  8043.5  4375.44562  Buy    22   False   
"2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863"  3997.87648  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy  1300   False   
"2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863"  3997.87616  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy     6   False   
"2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863"  3997.89530  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy  1000   False   
"2019-06-12 12:07:48.793863"  3997.90046  8044.0  4375.44562  Buy   280   False
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y = df['price']
x = np.arange(len(y))

# x:numpy.array, y:pandas.Series
segments_x = np.r_[x[0], x[1:-1].repeat(2), x[-1]].reshape(-1, 2)
segments_y = np.r_[y[0], y[1:-1].repeat(2), y[:-1]].reshape(-1, 2)
# print(segments_x, segments_y, sep='\n')
colors = ['green' if x == True else 'red' for x in df['signal']]
segments = [[x_, y_] for x_, y_ in zip(segments_x, segments_y)]
# print(segments)

for s,c in zip(segments, colors):
    ax.plot(s[0],s[1],color=c)

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['time'].tolist(), rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The color determination is based on the Boolean value of the signal column to create a list of colors.

Comment: Brilliant answer, simple, logical and to the point!